# Getting java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException from asyncTask on android

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, layout, android-asynctask

I am reading a sqlite database into a tableLayout. I wan't to do this in a seperate thread instead of having a long wait with no ui updates. So I used an AsyncTask to do some of the work and publish the results. However only about 1/4th of the item in my list actually make it on to the TableLayout. It works fine without the AsyncTask. Most of the items on the list throw an error (which I caught) java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException. I'm not sure why this is. Here is my code.

```
myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + TableName
                + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, filepath TEXT UNIQUE, title TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, time TEXT, playcount NUMERIC);");

        Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName, null);         

        c.moveToFirst();
        if (c != null) {
            int color = 0xFFdfe8ea;
            this.startManagingCursor(c);
            // Loop through all Results
            do {
                try{
                    MyAsyncTask aTask = new MyAsyncTask();
                    String[]strings= {c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("artist")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("album")),""+color};
                    aTask.execute(strings);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.w("****", e);
                }
        if (color == 0xFFdfe8ea) {
                    color = 0xFFf2f8fa;
                } else {
                    color = 0xFFdfe8ea;
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("****", e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (myDB != null) {
            myDB.close();
        }
    }
```

and here is the AsyncTask

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, View> {
    @Override
    protected View doInBackground(String... params) {
        int color = Integer.parseInt(params[4]);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView space = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        space.setText("");
        space.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
        space.setSingleLine();
        space.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        space.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        space.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        space.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                findViewById(R.id.spaceColumn).getWidth(),
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
        TextView title = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        title.setText(params[0]);
        title.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
        title.setSingleLine();
        title.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        title.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        title.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        title.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                0,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
        TextView artist = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        artist.setText(params[1]);
        artist.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
        artist.setSingleLine();
        artist.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        artist.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        artist.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        artist.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        artist.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                0,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
        TextView time = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        time.setText(params[2]);
        time.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
        time.setSingleLine();
        time.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        time.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        time.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        time.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                findViewById(R.id.timeColumn).getWidth(),
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
        TextView album = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        album.setText(params[3]);
        album.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
        album.setSingleLine();
        album.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        album.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        album.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        album.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        album.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                0,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        /* Add Button to row. */
        tr.addView(space);
        tr.addView(title);
        tr.addView(artist);
        tr.addView(time);
        tr.addView(album);

        /* Add row to TableLayout. */
        return tr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(View tr) {
        ((TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout)).addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
 }
```

---

For reference this is how I fixed it.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Song, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SQLiteDatabase myDB = openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String TableName = "songs";

        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + TableName
                + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, filepath TEXT UNIQUE, title TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, time TEXT, playcount NUMERIC);");

        Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        int filepathIndex=c.getColumnIndex("filepath");
        int titleIndex=c.getColumnIndex("title");
        int artistIndex=c.getColumnIndex("artist");
        int albumIndex=c.getColumnIndex("album");
        int timeIndex=c.getColumnIndex("time");
        int playcountIndex=c.getColumnIndex("playcount");

        if (c != null) {
            int color = 0xFFdfe8ea;
         //   this.startManagingCursor(c);
            // Loop through all Results
            do {
                Song song = new Song(c.getString(filepathIndex),c.getString(titleIndex),c.getString(artistIndex),c.getString(albumIndex),c.getString(timeIndex),c.getInt(playcountIndex),color);
                // Add to song the data from your cursor
                publishProgress(song);

                if (color == 0xFFdfe8ea) {
                    color = 0xFFf2f8fa;
                } else {
                    color = 0xFFdfe8ea;
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void item) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Song... items) {
        for (Song song : items) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView space = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            space.setText("");
            space.setBackgroundColor(song.color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            space.setSingleLine();
            space.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            space.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            space.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            space.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    findViewById(R.id.spaceColumn).getWidth(),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            TextView title = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            title.setText(song.title);
            title.setBackgroundColor(song.color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            title.setSingleLine();
            title.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            title.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            title.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
            title.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    0,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            TextView artist = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            artist.setText(song.artist);
            artist.setBackgroundColor(song.color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            artist.setSingleLine();
            artist.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            artist.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            artist.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            artist.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
            artist.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    0,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            TextView time = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            time.setText(song.time);
            time.setBackgroundColor(song.color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            time.setSingleLine();
            time.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            time.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            time.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            time.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    findViewById(R.id.timeColumn).getWidth(),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            TextView album = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            album.setText(song.album);
            album.setBackgroundColor(song.color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            album.setSingleLine();
            album.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            album.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            album.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            album.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
            album.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    0,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            /* Add Button to row. */
            tr.addView(space);
            tr.addView(title);
            tr.addView(artist);
            tr.addView(time);
            tr.addView(album);

            // Add the row to the table
            ((TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout)).addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never create Views from outside of the UI thread. You can execute your SQL query in doInBackground(), but create the View in onPostExecute().

Comment: @ghostbust555 What version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it using an AsyncTask, consider using `publishProgress()`, that way each item will be added as it is fetched from the database. This way:

**NOTE**: Consider that `Song` is a class with `name`, `album`, `artist` and `time` attributes.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Song, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TableName
            + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, filepath TEXT UNIQUE, title TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, time TEXT, playcount NUMERIC);");

        Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName, null);         

        c.moveToFirst();
        if (c != null) {
            int color = 0xFFdfe8ea;
            this.startManagingCursor(c);
            // Loop through all Results
            do {
                Song song = new Song();
                // Add to song the data from your cursor
                publishProgress(song);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void item) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }       

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Song... items) {
        for (Song song : items) {    
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView space = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            space.setText("");
            space.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            space.setSingleLine();
            space.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            space.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            space.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            space.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    findViewById(R.id.spaceColumn).getWidth(),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            TextView title = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            title.setText(song.getTitle());
            title.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            title.setSingleLine();
            title.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            title.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            title.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
            title.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    0,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            TextView artist = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            artist.setText(song.getArtist());
            artist.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            artist.setSingleLine();
            artist.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            artist.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            artist.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            artist.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
            artist.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    0,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            TextView time = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            time.setText(song.getTime());
            time.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            time.setSingleLine();
            time.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            time.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            time.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            time.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    findViewById(R.id.timeColumn).getWidth(),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            TextView album = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            album.setText(song.getAlbum());
            album.setBackgroundColor(color); //0xFFf2f8fa alternating
            album.setSingleLine();
            album.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            album.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            album.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            album.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
            album.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    0,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            /* Add Button to row. */
            tr.addView(space);
            tr.addView(title);
            tr.addView(artist);
            tr.addView(time);
            tr.addView(album);

            // Add the row to the table
            ((TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout)).addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
 }
```

I believe you understood the concept behind AsyncTask wrongly, I strongly suggest you reread [its documentation at Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as its concept is a bit tricky to understand but very powerfull when you do so. As Romain Guy commented on your answer you can only execute UI code on the onPreExecute(), onProgressUpdate() and onPostExecute() methods.

Comment: to be clear, publishUpdate(song) should be publishProgress(song) correct?

Comment: did u people noticed any "slowing down" just because u put this query in asyncTask? Can u take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224298/why-rawquery-in-asynctask-is-much-slower 10q

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing this RejectedExceutionException is almost certainly because you are submitting too many requests.

I just went into the code of AsyncTask and I noticed:

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);

/**
* An {@link Executor} that can be used to execute tasks in parallel.
*/
    public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
            = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);
```

That will build a bounded LinkedBlockingQueue. Up to 10 elements for the bound.  The 
MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE I saw was 128 (which means if needed the Executor will create 128 threads at most).

Once you exceed the 128 thread and submit to a  new MyTask instance with a queue depth of 10 you will get a RejectedExecutionException.  This exception is thrown when you saturate all available threads and there is no more room on the queue.

You can easily confirm this by getting a thread-dump when the RejectedExecution occurs.

Basically, you can submit 138 MyTask's at any particular time but once you submit 139+ at the same time (not within the life time of the app) you will run into this issue

***Edit:***  I went through the code more, and the most recent version (actually since Jan 16, 2011) this error should never happen.

With any version older then that you will run into this [issue](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/81de61bfddceba0eb77b3aacea317594b0f1de49#core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java).

In short, if you upgrade you version this issue will go away, however each task will be executed serially and not concurrently.

Comment: This error occurs when I call only 10 AsyncTasks though, and I am using  a fairly new version though I will try updating and report back.

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to create one AsyncTask for that. You are not fetching anything from the network or downloading images. Its just standard loading.

I would limit the result in the SQL with 'limit'.

Also, you are doing that inside an adapter right? Because I think you are adding everything to the list, where you should create a listview in your layout and set an Adapter. Maybe extending BaseAdapter.

Every adapter has a convenient method called getView that will get called only when it is visible and should help with your problem.

This is an example of an adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context = null;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public MyAdapter(Context context){

        this.context = context;     
        SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase();              
        this.cursor = db.query("YOUR QUERY");

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.cursor.getCount();
    }


    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LinearLayout row;

        try {           
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        if (convertView == null) {      
            row = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myRowLayout, parent, false);
            } else {
            row = (LinearLayout) convertView;
            }

        TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myLayoutId);
        name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("your column")));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            row = null;
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return row;

    }

    @Override
    public MoneyCurrency getItem(int position) {        
        this.cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        long id = this.cursor.getLong(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("your column id")); 
        return new Object.read(id, context, null); //Return whatever you want to show in that row. This is used if you want to use onClick listeners or menus
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        this.cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        return this.cursor.getLong(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("your id column"));
    }



    }
```

Comment: Im using a TableLayout with TableRows not a listView (although I was considering switching to listview somehow) but I want it to be a separate thread so that when there is a very large database you wont see a black screen for 15 seconds, the table will add a row then display that row and repeat

Comment: You can have a TableLayout for each item in the listview. But please see that you are querying the cursor outside the AsyncTask so that will happen even if you are using an adapter or running a process to fill the table. It's much more efficient to just use a listview. If the database is too large, using listview or threads of adapters wont help much since you probably need to limit it either way. What you want to do in a separate thread, will work inside the getView of the adapter. Makes sense?