# why rawQuery in AsyncTask is much slower..?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

Here is the case:
In my app, I have service which is used for communication with other special device. In the middle of this communictation I need to query database in my app to get data neccesary to  proceed communicating with 2nd device. Here I am using rawQuery with 2 parameters. Query is a not too complicated cause I am actually quering view in database. As a result I should get back around *50 rows* and *25 columns*.

The thing is that if I just call this query from service (same thread) it blocks my UI for like *6 seconds*. There is animation signaling long operation which got stuck.

On the other side, if I call exactly same query in doInBackground of AsyncTask (to move it from UI thread) my animation flows without troubles but for same amount of data query now need *25 seconds* til *1 minute* depending on which phone I am testing.. (almost 1min take on new Motorola with Intel cpu)

I measure times and where is so much time lost (cause queries and databases are exactly the same on both phones) and all this time is wasted on first access to cursor. In my case c.moveToFirst() ..

My question is more Android oriented not SQL, cause in my app I integrate already complete, filled with data, database

Any idea, anybody?

**Edit:**  I try different solutions for issue I have and here is interesting thing I came to: When I use another thread with Runnable which has query, time is reduced back to few seconds (exactly like everything is executed in UI thread)
***Thread t = new Thread(RunnableWhichHoldQuery);*** //then I just start thread t.

Still not sure why AsyncTask is behaving like it does.. Now I am just curious for explanation cause I would like to understand better what is going on.. thanks to everybody with ideas..

Comment: How many records does your query need to read (not *return*)?

Comment: Select * from that view will return around 20000.

Comment: did you use an index on your columns which are in WHERE part?

Comment: Please show your DB schema and the query.

Comment: as I said query is super simple like "SELECT * from myView where p=1 AND b='121' ORDER BY c".. Results are 25 coloumns and around 50 rows..

@Tomislav I can just read DB so what is there it is there.. no creating additional indexes. I just get db and integrate it in app. As far as I know there are no indexes on this view I am quering.

Comment: Are you running other AsyncTasks at that time ? What API version are you using ?

Comment: no other AsyncTask is started at that time but there is separate thread for communication between my phone and second device. However there is no communication at the moment of db query cause communication is waitng for data to proceed.

Comment: measurements are done on ICS on both phones..